# setting CFStream property failing

Tags: ios, ssl, nsstream, sni, cfstream

I'm trying to set up TLS connection with SNI. Problem is that the first property setting call returns 1 indicating that it was accepted. The following two return 0, which means they didn't go through. What could be the reasoning be?

At some point I have to add my own cert to be trusted, but as far as I understand, that will be done after opening the streams, so it shouldn't be any cause here.

Also, does `kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL` support tls1.2 as there are no constants to choose that directly?

```
    var tempInputStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var tempOutputStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, address as CFStringRef, port, &tempInputStream, &tempOutputStream)

    let cfInputStream: CFReadStream = tempInputStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    let cfOutputStream: CFWriteStream = tempOutputStream!.takeRetainedValue()

//setting properties
    print(CFReadStreamSetProperty(cfInputStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL))
    print(CFReadStreamSetProperty(cfInputStream, kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain, kCFBooleanFalse))
    print(CFReadStreamSetProperty(cfInputStream, kCFStreamSSLPeerName, "peer.address"))


    let inputStream: NSInputStream = cfInputStream
    let outputStream: NSOutputStream = cfOutputStream

    inputStream.delegate = self
    inputStream.delegate = self

    inputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    outputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    inputStream.open()
    outputStream.open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain` and `kCFStreamSSLPeerName` are not stream properties. They are SSL Settings properties. You need to collect them all together into a dictionary and assign it to `kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings`:

```
let ssl = [
    String(kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain): kCFBooleanFalse, // You an probably use "false" here
    String(kCFStreamSSLPeerName): "peer.address"
]

print(CFReadStreamSetProperty(cfInputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, ssl))
```